# Drop value from Play Json

Tags: json, playframework-2.0

I have a case class in Play:

```
case class Airport(name: String, iata: String, country:String)

object Airport {
  implicit val AirportAutoCompleteFormat = (
      (JsPath \ "name").format[String] and
      (JsPath \ "iata").format[String] and
      (JsPath \ "country").format[String]
    )(AirportAutoComplete.apply,unlift(AirportAutoComplete.unapply))

}
```

Now I would like to send an airport out via Ok(Json.toJson(..)) response. But I dont want to send out the country String. Can I somehow drop it?

Edit: working solution `Ok(Json.toJson(AirportList.map(Json.toJson(_).as[JsObject] - "country")))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `-`

For a val named `x`, you would use the following code:

`Ok(Json.toJson(x) - "country")`

From the JsObject Scaladoc: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.JsObject

Comment: But `Json.toJson` returns a `JsValue`, using

`Ok(Json.toJson(x).as[JsObject])`

gives me `JsResultException(errors:List((,List(ValidationError(error.expected.jsobject,WrappedArray())))))`

Any idea?

Comment: Ok problem was it was a List(). using `Ok(Json.toJson(AirportList.map(Json.toJson(_).as[JsObject] - "country")))` gives me the correct result. Can I make this prettier?

Comment: Is the initial `Json.toJson` needed? If it's just a list, you should be able to use `Ok(AirportList.map(Json.toJson(_).as[JsObject] - "country"))`

Comment: Otherwise I get `Cannot write an instance of List[play.api.libs.json.JsObject] to HTTP response. Try to define a Writeable[List[play.api.libs.json.JsObject]]`